# 検索エンジンduckduckGoの検索結果でロケーションを日本にしてスクレイピングしたい(node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

duckduckGoの検索結果をロケーションを日本にした場合で取得できるようになりたいです。

node.jsのcheerio-httpcliを使ってduckduckGoの検索結果をスクレイピングしました。
しかし帰ってくる結果はロケーションを日本にした場合と異なる結果でした

```
**「虫歯 原因」の検索結果（現状）**

巨大虫歯に挑む - YouTube
虫歯治療 - YouTube
Eeデンタル【虫歯が原因で大量の膿!】 でも抜かない根管治療専門医
角化嚢胞性歯原性腫瘍 - Wikipedia
```

```
**ロケーションを日本に指定した場合の検索結果**

虫歯ができる7つの原因と自分にあった予防法
虫歯の原因は？虫歯はどうしてできるの？ | 水天宮・人形町の ...
虫歯になりやすい習慣・環境とは？原因や検査、セルフ ...
虫歯の原因とは？歯を磨いてるのになぜ虫歯になるの？
```

上記のように今のままだと中国語やキーワードによってはロシア語？が混じった検索結果が帰ってきます。

```
現状のソースコード(Express.js)
const client = require('cheerio-httpcli'),
  $ = require('jquery'),
　targetURL = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html';

async function duckGo (keyword) {
  return await client.fetch(targetURL, { q: keyword })
    .then(result => {
           //返ってきたDOMをトリムする処理が入っている
           ...
        }); 
        return duckObj;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
exports.duckGo = duckGo
```

おそらくheadersの情報を変更すれば行けるのかな。と考えfetch()の直前に

client.set('headers', {
  'x-duckduckgo-locale': 'ja_JP'    
});

上記のコードを入れてみましたが結果は変わらずです。実は違うタイトルでteratailsでも質問させていただいたのですが、２日待っても回答を得られずこちらでも質問させていただいた次第です。（タイトルと質問内容も少し変えて質問しました）

**他に試したこと**
パラメータを追加してみましたがダメでした。

**備考**
https://duckduckgo.com/html/
上記はduckduckGoの検索結果を静的サイトとして表示できるリンクです。通常の検索結果は動的サイトとして表示されるためcheerioでスクレイピングできません。

ブラウザからみた場合のヘッダー情報

```
**General**
Request URL: https://duckduckgo.com/html/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 54.254.135.186:443
Referrer Policy: origin

**Response Headers**
access-control-allow-origin: https://duckduckgo.com
access-control-expose-headers: 
cache-control: max-age=1
content-encoding: br
content-security-policy: default-src https: blob: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self'
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 24 May 2020 03:52:22 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=0
expires: Sun, 24 May 2020 03:52:23 GMT
referrer-policy: origin
server: nginx
server-timing: total;dur=349;desc="Backend Total"
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-duckduckgo-locale: ja_JP
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1;mode=block

**Response Headers**
:authority: duckduckgo.com
:method: POST
:path: /html/
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 42
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: kl=jp-jp; ah=jp-jp%2Cth-th; l=jp-jp; kl=ja-ja
origin: https://duckduckgo.com
referer: https://duckduckgo.com/
sec-fetch-dest: document
```

Comment: HTTP request/response をトレースしてみると、request header に User-agent と Accept-Language と Upgrade-Insecure-Requests が指定されています。これらを curl コマンドで指定してアクセスしてみると想定される検索結果を得られます。`curl -s --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0 Waterfox/56.3' -H 'Accept-Language:ja,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1' 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%E8%99%AB%E6%AD%AF+%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0&b='` ただ、短期間の間に繰り返し実行すると、質問欄の最初にある様な検索結果になりますのでサーバ側でチェックしている可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
いただいた３種類のヘッダー情報を指定してPOSTしたところ望んだ結果が得られました。POSTする環境ごとに違う結果を返すよう指定されているんですね。勉強なります。